# Hosts not resolving in host file

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, debian, bind

I'm trying to add hosts in the `/etc/hosts` file and they're simply not resolving. I've restarted `/etc/init.d/networking` and didn't solve the issue. I've looked at `nsswitch.conf` file and appear to attempt to resolve names by host file first then `mdns` then `dns`, so that looks correct. FYI I'm studying for my OSCP exam. These machine I'm hacking are from hackthebox.eu and are meant to hacked for practice.

```
root@kali:~# getent hosts admin-portal.europacorp.htb
root@kali:~# 


root@kali:~# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   kali



10.10.10.22 www.admin-protal.europacorp.htb

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
root@kali:~# 

root@kali:~# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
netgroup:       nis
root@kali:~#
```

Comment: You do see that `admin-portal` is misspelled in the `hosts` file?

Answer (score 1):

You entered `www.admin-protal.europacorp.htb` into your hosts file.

You are trying to resolve `admin-portal.europacorp.htb`, which doesn't exist in your hosts file.

The `www.` is missing and `portal` is misspelled.

Comment: It's not working either way.root@kali:~# getent hosts admin-portal.europacorp.htb
root@kali:~# getent hosts admin-protal.europacorp.htb
root@kali:~#